# Allow user to mark attendance Once per day

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I am working on Attendance Management System.I want the user to mark attendance once per day.

> How can i put a constraint for allowing users to mark once per day..Either i restrict the button after clicking or i can do something in database logic.

```
           DBreference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                   currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

                   String present ="Present";
                   DBreference.child("Attendance").child(currentDateTimeString).setValue(present);
                   Toast.makeText(ProfileAct.this, "Marked as Present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }

               @Override
               public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
           });
            break;
        case R.id.cardLeave:
            DBreference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                    currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
                    String present ="On Leave";
                    DBreference.child("Attendance").child(currentDateTimeString).setValue(present);
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileAct.this, "Marked As Leave", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });`
```

Comment: You should have use database logic here according to 24 hours.

Comment: Can u please help how to do that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a listener to your path only for the day not the time:

```
Date cDate = new Date();
String fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cDate);

e.g. DBreference.child("Attendance").(fDate)
```

And add the value "Present" or "Absent" on this path.

Then attach a ValueEventListener on this path. And you get a callback of a value present in this path in the onDataChange, you can disable your button or view if there is a value found.

[ValueEventListener Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener)

Comment: Hope it will help.Let me Implement the logic..Thanks

Comment: it is also getting the time,,,not just date

Comment: ohh..my mistake..thats ok

Comment: Thats ok..Now i want to check that if this date is available.How to query that,,i have updated the image.Kindly check it.Thanks

Comment: attach a ValueEventListener to the path: DBreference.child("Attendance").(fDate)

where date is either today's date based on the System.currentTimeMillis() or from Calendar class if you have are using a Calendar widget.

And then if the onDataChange callback is called you have a value, which means you could disable your button/ui to mark the attendance if it isn't called there's no value and you let your UI be enabled

Answer (score 0):

Your database need to create daily entries according to date and then you will check from your front end side that user is attended or not if yes then you need to store a boolean flag in database and you will have to check before user giving attendance that he/she have already gave or not using that flag.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to actually have a node for attendance. Firebase encourages flat data than nested data. Then you can create a child for each day, with a user to check for the day. This way even your data querying is easier. Here is an example

```
attendance : {
    "12/03/2019" : {
        "UID" : "time stamp"
    },
    "11/03/2019" : {
        "UID" : "time stamp"
    }
}
```